# How to calculate combinations with no set number of participants?

Tags: combinatorics

I apologies for such a simple questions but I'm not sure why I have results that I have.

If there are 5 differently colored balls which needs to go in a box, in how many combinations can I throw the balls in without the color set repeating?
No importance to the amount of balls go in.

If the answer held importance on the order of things then it would have been a simple  factorial of 5.
The answer to this problem is 5 squared and I can't figure out why.

thank you in advance.

Comment: isn't it rather $2^5$ ?

Comment: Could you clarify the question with an example? Eg list the possibilities for 3 balls.

Comment: thank you. what I meant is, say I have Red, Blue, Yellow- I can put in just Red or Red+Blue or Red+Yellow or Red +BLUE+Yellow or Yellow and etc...As long as no set of colors would be matched twice.     Pierre Alvarez- Ummm... I don't think so but I'm not sure...Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment regarding $n=3$, for $n=5$, there can be no balls; or a single ball which can happen 5 ways which could write as ${5 \choose 1}$, or 2 balls which can happen $5 \choose 2$ ways, or 3 balls which can happen $5 \choose 3$ ways, etc up to 5 balls, which can happen ${5 \choose 5} = 1$ way.

So what you want, for $n=5$, is

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}$$

which from the binomial theorem equals $2^n$, or in your case with $n=5$, $2^5 = 32$.

You can think about this another way: suppose $n=3$ and we have red, green and blue balls. Given a collection of balls you put in the box, we can write the ordered triple $(n_{red}, n_{green}, n_{blue})$ where $n_{red}$ is the number of red balls in the collection, and so on.

By the constraints of your problem, each $n_{(color)}$ must be either 0 or 1. The possibilities are easily seen to map to the binary numbers from 0 to 7 inclusive; so there are $2^3 = 8$ possibilities.

This can be extended - suppose your problem was that there can only be at most 2 balls of any given color in the box. Then we can consider the ordered tuples $(n_{red}, n_{green}, n_{blue})$ where each $n_{(color)}$ is 0, 1, or 2. This possibilities in that case can be mapped to the three digit numbers base 3; so there are $3^3 = 27$ possibilities in that case.